# Can this question about anomalous dimensions and operator mixing be reopend?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen

I edited [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24409/2751) question to remomve the reference request issue and think it should be reopend now.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure about how to interpret the downvotes of both, asking on meta if a question can be reopend, and my answer. If it is personal and people are just downvoting because I have asked this, this is ok. But asking on meta, if a question can be reopend is per se legitimate and an [encouraged](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4114/2751) way to go to resolve disagreements. I hope people who downvote my answer here understand at least what the anomalous dimension question is asking about, and dont downvote just because they dislike advanced topic technical questions ...

Comment: Downvotes on meta often indicate disagreement, so people who are downvoting your question may be doing so because they disagree that the question should be reopened. You shouldn't jump straight to assuming that it is personal.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky people who disagree with me and who agree with you can vote accordingly on both of our answers explaining the reasons for the different point of view. But I see no point in downvoting the question itself, since asking of a question can be reopend after it has been edited is a legitimate use of meta. This is why I edited my reasoning out of the question and put it into an answer, such that people can downvote my answer if they disagree.

Comment: Since the last elections, everything I post on meta has to overcome an obstructive potential wall of 4 or 5 people's downvotes, before the net score can become neutral or even positive. First, this annoyed me a lot, then I got used to it, and now I consider it to be rather amusing :-D.  What is sligthly less funny is that for example technical questions about advanced topics can not be reopent if they are closed once, because I am almost the only one caring to get such questions reopend.

Comment: This is bad since in view of the large number of really low level questions ramped up since yesterday. I flagged about 20 who are worse than good HW questions. Good HW questions about interesting topics I even appreciate. But in view of the increased number of really low level questions, technical questions about advanced topics should be encouraged and not discouraged by getting closed and stay closed.

Comment: (3 comments up) It does no good to complain to me, I'm just telling you how downvotes tend to be used on meta sites.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky yes, obviously nothing can be done about it. These popular science, laypeople, and very basic questions and their answers get higher upvoted than technocal or advanced topis questions. People get more rep from basic questions and answers, such that they will soon have access to moderation priviledges and dominate the site. In fact it has already started and this transition is irreversible.

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to downvote this. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I'll copy my reasoning here: while it's certainly better than it was as a resource recommendation, the question is still unfocused. It says

> I am looking for an explanation about the idea of "operator mixing" and its associated concept about when anomalous dimension has to be thought of as a matrix.

but it does not specify what about operator mixing needs to be explained. What about operator mixing and anomalous dimensions does the OP want to know? The definitions? What they are used for? Some particular aspect of how they are used? Etc. We're waiting for clarification from the OP about what exactly he/she wants to ask.

Answer (score -1):

At a first look, one could think that the question still asks too many things in a too incoherent manner, but Mitchell Porter was able to correctly understand the question.

To me, asking about two nearly related enough concepts such as operator mixing and anomalous dimension, giving an example of what one wants to better understand from knowing these concepts (the equation in the paper), plus investigating if these two concepts are known under other names in the literature (which could be confusing) too, is legitimate and makes a lot of sense to me too.

Comment: Clearly the user is not active for quite a long time and it is unlikely that he would fix such an old question, my advise in this situation is identify the precise question whose answer you are interested in and post it as a separate question. Perhaps Porter would be interested in answering it. Personally these concepts are new to me and I would be interested in learning more about them.

Comment: @Prathyush he was [active](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1637/user6818?tab=activity) on Mai 16th this year, he is still here asking, commenting etc ... I am interested in answers to this question too, maybe I'll have ask about certain things the question contains indeed, if it does not get reopend.

Comment: I disagree.  If a person is going to ask about 'professional' topics, the onus is on that person to write clearly enough that it's obvious to most technically able persons exactly what the question is.  This question needs clarification, IMHO.  This particular user has a bad habit of asking people whose time is valuable for a lot of effort in exchange for little public benefit.

Comment: @user1504 the answers are of interest to other people too, they are not exclusively for the OP who may or may not deserve them.

Comment: A proper answer downvoted until it fades away? +1.